# Voxel perfect model where a light can change the color of each voxel instance with no gradients/shadows using Geometry nodes?

Tags: materials, geometry-nodes, shaders

I made a voxel-izer by using geometry nodes' instance on points node. Here’s an example as well as the geometry node setup:

Before:
[image]

After:
[image]

Geometry node settup:
[image]

Material setup:

[image]

I wanted to apply a cell shader material to the model by using the color ramp and principled bsdf nodes. I initially thought this would change the color of each voxel instance, but instead it  placed gradients/shadows on top of the voxels.

Cell Shaded Material setup:
[image]
Examples circled:
[image]

My goal is to make a voxel perfect model with no gradients where a light can change the color of each voxel instance. My guess would be that I would need to use the geometry proximity node in order to switch each voxel instance to a different lighter material in order to achieve this, but I don’t know how to implement this idea nor do I know if there’s a better way of doing it. Can anybody help with this?

[image]